# Unity light baked very badly on stairways and other holes

Tags: unity-game-engine, light

I've already baked light in this project. And it WAS good. But yesterday when I baked it again there were some artifacts on stairways and doorway.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I tried to change lightmapping settings, but it didn't help. I've seen this artefacts above ceiling, but in that case player can't see them. There are my lightmapping settings:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed!

I'm using Pro Builder and when in Pro Builder i moved those polygons where was this artefacts a bit and baked light again - it fixed. I think it was bug or smth that in result it generated bad UV and when i moved it - Pro Builder generated it again(my guesses).